# Form validation with Key Press Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Last night, I got a call from our supervisor indicating that when he attempted to log in to our app with dummy password, his validation was successful.

It turns out that clicking the mouse to authenticate password worked fine as users with invalid password were denied access.

However, entering password and hitting the `ENTER` key on the keyboard would allow users access to the system.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it from continuing to happen?

```
   Protected Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click

        Dim StrPass As String
        Dim BValid As Boolean
        Dim rs As SqlDataReader
        Dim StrSQL As String

        'Protect against SQL Injection
        StrPass = Replace(txtPass.Text, "'", "''", 1, -1, 1)

        ' This is our boolean variable for validation purposes set to true if valid user
        BValid = False



        StrSQL = "select * from users u " & _
       " Where u.pass =@pass"

        ' Initialize Database Connection
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconn").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(StrSQL, conn)

        'We use parametized query to prevent sql injection attack
        Dim p1 As New SqlParameter("@pass", StrPass)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)

        'Now open connection to the db
        conn.Open()

        'open recordset to receive db values
        rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()

           While rs.Read()
            If rs("pass") <> "" Then
                Session("pass") = txtPass.Text
                BValid = True
            Else
            End If
        End While

        ' No leaking allowed
        conn.Close()

        ' This handles all response per validation
        If BValid = True Then
            dbto.Hide()
        Else
            'If all else fails, then reject their athentication attempt and let them hear it.
            lblWrong.Text = "Incorrect pass entered."
        End If
    End Sub
```

'markup

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPass" Text="Please enter Password: " Font-Size="14pt"/>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPass" TextMode="Password" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblWrong" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="Tahoma" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Im assuming clicking the button hits the above routine, but does hitting enter hit it as well?

Comment: @Dylan, no and that's the issue. hitting the `enter` doesn't seem to be hitting anything. As a result, it just ignores it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your content in panel and assign Default button.

Comment: what do you by Default button?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btn"> Your Content
</asp:Panel>

Comment: I do have that already. However, when I added DefaultButton="", I got the following:

`The DefaultButton of 'panel1' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl`

Comment: yes you have to assign the id of the button in DefaultButton if the id of your button is btnXYZ then you have to write DefaultButton="btnXYZ "